# Javascript - Create array dynamically in object and push to it

Tags: javascript

How do I populate `filters`.

```
let filters = {};
```

To make it look like this:

```
filters = {
  color: ["Blue", "Black"],
  size: [70, 50]
};
```

So if I would have a function:

```
function populate(key, value) {
    //if key is color value gets pushed to filters.color
    //if key is size value gets pushed to filters.size
    //if any other key, create new property with new name
}
```

So doing this would result in a new array in filters:

```
populate(material, "plastic");
```

And filters would look like this:

```
filters = {
  color: ["Blue", "Black"],
  size: [70, 50],
  material: ["plastic"]
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `in` to check if the key exists in the object. Based on that push the value in the object array otherwise creates a new key with array value.

```js
let filters = {};
filters = {
  color: ["Blue", "Black"],
  size: [70, 50]
};

function populate(key, value) {
    //if key is color value gets pushed to filters.color
    //if key is size value gets pushed to filters.size
    //if any other key, create new property with new name
    if(key in filters)
      filters[key].push(value);
    else
      filters[key] = [value];
}
populate('material', "plastic");
console.log(filters);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something simple as this, where you check if the key exist and then *push* or *assign*.

```
array[key] ? array[key].push(value) : array[key] = [value];
```

*Do note, you need to pass the key "material" as a string, and I as well recommend to pass the array too, to make the function more reusable.*

```js
filters = {
  color: ["Blue", "Black"],
  size: [70, 50]
};

function populate(a, k, v) {
  a[k] ? a[k].push(v) : a[k] = [v];
}

populate(filters, "material", "plastic");

console.log(filters)
```

Comment: won't that replace filters[key] with a new value every time the value will be `material`? I need to keep pushing new values to `color`, `size` or `material`

Comment: @Ciprian Updated again...somewhat more optimized, and reuseable

Comment: If you want to compress it a turnary might be good `a[k] = a[k] ? a[k].push(v) : [v];`

Comment: @AndrewBone That won't work... this one though `a[k] ? a[k].push(v) : a[k] = [v];`, so thanks

Comment: @AndrewBone Try it by calling _populate_ 2 times and you'll see. After second _populate_ the value is 2, not e.g. `"plastic", "paper"`

Comment: Oh, interesting, "The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array". Learnt something new, thanks 

Comment: `a[k] = a[k] ? a[k].concat(v) : [].concat(v);` works and allows you to pass in a whole array

Comment: @AndrewBone Yes, though mine/yours is shorter...and another answer already make use of `concat`, and is shorter than your version :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method of array if key present in `filters` Object otherwise it you will assign new array with new value.

**DEMO**

```js
var filters = {
  color: ["Blue", "Black"],
  size: [70, 50]
};

function populate(key, value) {
  filters[key] = (filters[key]||[]).concat(value); 
}

populate('material', "plastic");
populate('color', "Red");
populate('size',55);
console.log(filters)
```

```css
 .as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```